# Functions are not being highlighted in Python2.7 in Pycharm-community

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm-community 2016 0.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. 
I'm coding in Python 2.7, the problem is that the functions which are defined  by me are not being syntax-highlighted. For example, before using Pycharm I was using Atom, in it the functions are highlighted making it very easy to debug.

I have turned on Semantic highlighting and i'm using the theme 'Dracula'.

I tried to re install Pycharm-communty, tried installing the latest edition, but none if it  is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around foe this problem,
If you install the 'onedark' theme and enable it, the local functions are also highlighted.

To install,

go to settings > plugins >  search for 'onedark', and install